# Python - copy text on mouse click

Tags: python, copy, click, mouse, clipboard

I have the following area with a list of items (which refreshes regularly).
Whenever a particular row is clicked with mouse, the row is highlighted in blue. I would like to copy only the the text in the first column and selected row.

In this image example, I would like to copy 'GMBTW' into clipboard.

Appreciate any help or examples which can achieve this. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: TKinter, Kivy, QT, GTK, wxWindows?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you pls. point me to an example using one of these. I looked up and was not able to find any.